# Set redux-firestore listener using FieldPath in query

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm trying to set a listener with redux-firestore that queries firestore documents that has nested properties like this: users.USER_EMAIL.role. I need to be able to insert a variable in the where parameter of the query. I have done this previously using FieldPath without hooking up redux, but can't seem to make it work with redux-firestore.

Here's how I would do it before, which works fine:
`db.collection('projects').where(new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('users', email, 'role'), '==', 'owner')`

This is what I'm trying to do now, which fails:
`store.firestore.setListener({ collection: 'projects', where: [[new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('users', this.props.email, 'role'), '==', 'owner']] })`

I'm getting this error:

> Error: where parameter must be an array.

The where parameter looks like an array to me. What am I missing? Is it even possible to use FieldPath with redux-firestore?

Thanks!